# Put an RMarkdown::Render inside a future function in ShinyApp

Tags: r, promise, shiny, r-markdown, future

I have a shiny app and need to place an RMarkdown::render within a 'future' function to enable other users to continue using the app while the RMD loads/renders. The code below works when running the app and clicking the download button. However, when I uncomment the new code, implement the future, and run the app, I get an error "object 'params' can't be found."

```
output$snapshot_report_pdf_download <- downloadHandler( 

      filename = function() {
        if(trimws(input$snap_print_pdf_save_name,"both") == "") {
          "Portfolio Snapshot Report.pdf"
        } else {
          paste0(input$snap_print_pdf_save_name, ".pdf")              
        }
      },

      content = function(file){
        params <- list(
          ohf_sh_obj = ohf_sh_obj,
          data_date = ohf_sh_obj$data_date,
          report = "portfolio_snapshot",
          graph = input$snap_print_graphs,
          wl_selection_snap = input$wl_selection_snap,
          date_selection_snap = input$date_selection_snap,
          stacked_snap = input$stacked_snap
           )

        out <- render('scripts/printing/report_pdf.rmd')

        file.rename(out, file)

        if (file.exists("scripts/printing/report_pdf.rmd")) {
          file.remove("scripts/printing/report_pdf.rmd")
         }

        # future({render('scripts/printing/report_pdf.rmd',
        #                params = params)},
        #        globals = T,
        #        packages = c("knitr", "rmarkdown")) %...>%
        #   (function(result) {
        #     file.rename(result, file)                
        }
      })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar--but not identical--problem to yours in that I needed to use `render()` inside a future. I ended up just creating a `render_async()` fx:

```
    render_async <- function(file_path, params){
      future({
        render("report/GA_report.Rmd", 
             output_format = "all", 
             output_file = file_path,
             params = params, 
             envir = new.env(), 
             run_pandoc = TRUE)
      })
    }

    report$filepath <- render_async(tmp_file, params)
```

I think the reason that your `params` aren't being found is that the `future()` statement runs whatever is inside of it in a separate `R` session which is what is allowing other users to user your app while the `future()` is running. If you end up doing something similar to what I show above, your `params` obj will be in the session in which the `render()` statement is running and the error *should* go away.